# Setting up the child theme so as to enable right-to-left WordPress?

Tags: php, functions, child-theme, customization

I want to make a child theme for `twentyfifteen` theme in WordPress to show in right-to-left direction.
I read the documentation on that in [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes). But to be honest, the documentation was good for a general outline of the setup but not so clear on details and in case the theme already has an RTL support.

These were my steps:

created a child theme directory named `twentyfifteen-ar`

created a file `functions.php` inside the directory that only contains:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}
?>
```

created `style.css` file inside the same dir that only contains:

```
/*
Theme Name: Twenty Fifteen AR
Theme URI: https://wordpress.org/themes/twentyfifteen/
Author: me
Version: 1.0
Template: twentyfifteen
*/
```

After that, activated the newly appearing theme `Twenty Fifteen AR` but nothing changed from the parent theme. What am I missing please?

**Follow Up Question:**

I want to add this to CSS of `rtl.css` file for example (where to put this code?)

```
.wpcf7
        {
            background-color: #f7f7f7;
            border: 2px solid #0f0;
        }
```

Trials:

1. when created `rtl.css` inside child theme folder and added this code, website didn't pick up the change.
2. Worked only when I added this code in the parent `rtl.css` file of the parent 2015 theme, but I know this is not the best practice as it will soon be replaced of the new version of the theme when is out there. So how should I add this code in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to include the RTL.css file which is in the theme too:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
 wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'rtl-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/rtl.css' );
}
```

To use the rtl.css from your theme directory change the code to:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
 wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
 wp_enqueue_style( 'rtl-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/rtl.css' );
}
```

Make sure you copy everything from the original rtl.css file to your own.

Comment: the parent theme `twentyfifteen` does have `rtl.css` file, do I need to create another `rtl.css` file *inside* the child theme directory? if yes, what should its content be?

Comment: no, look at my code, I am puiling it in so it should then make the theme RTL

Comment: I see, great, I tried your kindly provided code and it worked, now I have RTL 2015 theme. Thanks.

Comment: wish I had enough points to add the tag `right-to-left`.

Comment: no worries, glad it was an easy thing to fix :)

Comment: Hi, say I want to fiddle a bit with CSS of the `rtl.css` file: like see code above (updated post), where should I add it?

Comment: another tiny question? how can one get the right label names you provided in your answer `parent-style` and `rtl-style`? is it any name you put or must be taken from somewhere?

Comment: Put whatever you want, they are just descriptive names

Comment: thanks, could you please care about the follow up question too?

Comment: amended my answer :)

Comment: great and very generous, unfortunately I cannot upvote thrice!

Comment: so how can I use parent theme's rtl.css without any changes? Do I have to copy?